# Mass plotting ODE curves that are solved from a list of parameter values

Tags: python, scipy, ode

My code is an ODE system that I can plot curves for. However, I wish to have 100 different solutions generated, for which I can then plot all 100 as curves onto one figure. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000

I0, R0 = 1, 0

S0 = N - I0 - R0
J0 = I0

beta, gamma = 2/7, 1/7

t = np.linspace(0, 160, 160+1)


def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R, J = y
    dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
    dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
    dR = (gamma * I)
    dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
    return dS, dI, dR, dJ


solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
S, I, R, J = solve.T

J_diff = np.diff(J)

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.plot(t[1:], J_diff, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Daily incidence')
ax.set_xlabel('Time in days')
ax.set_ylabel('Number (1000s)')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
legend = ax.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

This yields a curve such as this

[image]

However, I wish to calculate the ODE equation J for a list of random 100 beta values, all other parameters kept fixed, which I can plot so I get 100 curves. What I have tried is using something like:

```
empty = []
for i in range(100):
    empty.append(random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)*gamma)
```

for the new list of beta values, and then do

```
solns =  []
for empt in empty:
    ces = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, empty, gamma))
    solns.append(ces)
```

but this is not correct. I don't know if I'm thinking about it the wrong way or syntax is incorrect as opposed to the logic. Is it even possible to take each beta value in the list `empty`, calculate the ODE system for it, and the plot each solution on to one figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The problem is that you are passing a list of beta values instead of a single scalar due to a minor typo in the `args` argument. It should be

```
solns =  []
for empt in empty:
    ces = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, empt, gamma))
    solns.append(ces)
```

Then, you can proceed similarly to your code snippet, i.e.

```
J_diffs = []
for sol in solns:
    S, I, R, J = sol.T
    J_diffs.append(np.diff(J))

# plot all the solutions
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Time in days')
ax.set_ylabel('Number (1000s)')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')

for J_diff in J_diffs:
    ax.plot(t[1:], J_diff, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Daily incidence')

# plot without legend
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the clairification! I thought perhaps python would encounter a dimensional error, seeing as how one parameter is a list, but every other is just a set parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code shorter by making the loops into list generators,

```
empty = [ random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)*gamma  for _ in range(100) ]
```

or using the numpy method

```
empty = np.random.uniform(1.5, 2.5, size=100)*gamma
```

and

```
solns =  [ odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, bet, gamma))  for bet in empty ]
```

If you set custom tolerances or other parameters, it might make sense to encapsulate these constant parameters into a `mysolver` function that has only the likely changing parameters as arguments, `beta` and probably also `gamma` and `t`.

Comment: With this method I'm assuming the list generator nullifies the need for appending to the list later?

Comment: Yes. The lists are completely constructed at once, the details of the list construction left to the interna of python. There might be more specific tools in the itertools library.